# Principal Components Analysis Error X must be numeric but my column contains positive and negative number and yes or no

Tags: r, pca

I have a csv file which consists of 10 k rows of data. I am trying to perform PCA prcomp on the dataset. The data consists of 4 columns which are Money, Pay, Balance and Enough.
I tried to perform PCA on the dataframe below and it mention the error,

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I understand that the data need to be numeric but I only see numeric data only except the enough column. Even though I work on the 1st to 3rd column, it still did not work and mention the same error.

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

I tried to remove the - sign under the Balance column and when I tried to perform PCA, it work. Isnt -12345 a numeric?

I understand that non-numeric must not be stored in the data as PCA will not work. Is it possible to work on the data if it consist of Yes or No.

```
Money Pay  Balance Enough
24    25   -1      No
30    26   4       Yes
40    45   -5      No
31    20   11      Yes
```

My R code

```
results <- prcomp(dataf, scale = TRUE)
```

Comment: Convert your `Enough` column to a binary flag.  Usually, 1="Yes", 0="No".  Also, the left alignment of your `Balance` column suggests that might be a character as well.

Comment: @Limey I understand about the Balance column, may I kindly ask on how to solve the Balance Issue? How to transform negative number to an numeric?

Comment: A negative number *is* numeric.  I suspect the column is a character, not a numeric.  What is the output from `class(<mydf>$Balance)`? (Where you should replace `<mydf>` with the name of your data frame, which you haven't provided.)  Is the output `character` or `numeric`?  If the latter, you're OK.  If the former, `<mydf>$Balance <- as.numeric(<mydf>$Balance)` should do the trick.

Comment: @Limey I have performed as.numeric on the column, Balance and it still showed the same error.

Comment: I performed class(<mydf>$Balance) and it showed numeric before performing as.numeric and after.